# Spring boot JDBC exceptions

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm  new to java developer. I try to make a simple spring app using intellij IDE but I got bunch of exceptions I couldn't figure out

```
package ins.ne.GesionScolarite;

import ins.ne.GesionScolarite.Entities.Frais;
import ins.ne.GesionScolarite.dao.FraisRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GesionScolariteApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
@Autowired
private FraisRepository fraisRepository;
public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(GesionScolariteApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
fraisRepository.save(new Frais(null,340000));
fraisRepository.save(new Frais(null,500000));

fraisRepository.findAll().forEach(f -> {
System.out.println(f.toString());
    });
}
}
```

this is the main method but CommandLineRunner failed to execute.

```
package ins.ne.GesionScolarite.Entities;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
@Entity
@Data 
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor 
@ToString
public class Frais implements Serializable {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private int montant;
}
```

here is one Entity class I made

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scolarite
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =
spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto  = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

this is the application properties where JDBC is not found and the exceptions i got after fixing jdbc below

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at ins.ne.GesionScolarite.GesionScolariteApplication.main(GesionScolariteApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:212) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect ]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect 
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:351) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
```

Comment: You have invalid `jdk:` prefix in your db configuration

Comment: ok. how can I fix it? thanks in advance

Comment: Please check you don't have another property file that override values in your file

Comment: Edit your question/ask a new question with the new exception

Comment: below are new exceptions i got after fixing jdbc

Answer (score 1):

MySQL jdbcUrl should be in format

```
jdbc:mysql://host[:port]/dbname
```

As error suggest, you have `jdk:` prefix that should be removed

```
not accept jdbcUrl, jdk:mysql://localhost:3306/scolarite
```

Comment: here is my application properties                                                  spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scolarite
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =
#spring.datasource.driverClassName= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto  = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Comment: @ AbdoulayeIbroLaouali check your hibernate jars and see
  https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Hibernate4

Comment: thanks user7294900 for helping me. as i told you, I'm new to java. so I want you to tell me how to check that if possible

Comment: @AbdoulayeIbroLaouali see
 https://www.findjar.com/class/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL5Dialect.html